# Safely encoding <script> content in ASP.NET Core (ETAGO Problem)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

The project I am working on requires user generated server data to be encoded to JSON and sent down with the HTML document in script tags. At the moment I am doing this with the `TagBuilder` class using the `InnerHtml.AppendHtml(...)` method to write the script content.

I have since discovered I have to escape / encode the script content as if the user content has for whatever reason the text `"</script>"`somewhere, the HTML parser ends the script tag (other HTML probably has various side effects as well).

I read [this](https://www.man42.net/blog/2016/12/safely-escape-user-data-in-a-script-tag/) blog post which describes how to handle the situation in an Node.js environment by using the jsesc library. Does anything similar exist for .NET (ideally Core or Standard)?

I wanted to ask before I roll my own as I'm always weary of doing that for security related code.

*Edit*

Due to time constraints, for the time being I have injected the JSON into a HTML element as an attribute value, and the ASP.Net Core engine automatically encodes those correctly.

Unfortunately it does increase the size of the HTML document a little more than I would like, as double quotes are encoded as `&quot;`, but it is what it is.

I'm leaving this question open though in case an answer to my original question comes along.

Comment: Suggestion: just [base64-encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) your JSON string, for example with JS `btoa()`.

Comment: @paulsm4: That makes it bigger though.

Comment: @paulsm4 Unfortunately `btoa/atob` only work on ASCII strings and we have to support Unicode.